# How do I see Daily Active Users from Firebase Analytics?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

[image]

I believe the above section from my Firebase Analytics shows average active users by 28days, 7days, 1day range (do correct me if i'm wrong. I'm still confused as to what it really means.) How can I view number of users per day?

Answer (score 0):

The number of users per day is "1-day" users, so to see the numbers you need to point your mouse at turquoise line at the given point of time, like below:

[image: users graph with highlighted one day users]